# Probability of a coin dropping in a box

Tags: probability

suppose I am going to toss a coin of diameter 1 inch in a square box that has length of 2 inch .Whats the probability of the coin dropping in the box but will not touch the border?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your efforts at solving the problem.

Comment: area of coin/area of box

Comment: @Tekton_infernus :  favourable area / total area

Comment: now how do i get favourable area ? why area of the coin is not favourable?

Comment: It may depend on the angle at which you drop the coin

Comment: This is horribly underspecified.  With what probability distribution and what sample space does the coin enter the box?  A highly precise robot can with $100\%$ accuracy land the coin in the box without touching the edges every single time.  A small child on the other hand might not even successfully get the coin in the box when trying...

Comment: @Henry that might make things more complex

Comment: And what happens near the corners? If the centre of the coin is just inside the corner, almost 3/4 of the coin is outside the edges of the box. Does it go in or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple drawing you realize that the probability is

$$\frac{1^2}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

[image]

that is the area of the red square divided by the total area

Comment: This makes wild unjustified assumptions as to the probability distribution at play here.

Comment: @JMoravitz ...assuming uniform distribution in the square

Comment: @tommik thats the answer I was looking for,thanks

Comment: @tommik can you please explain why can't i divide area of coin/whole area of box?I mean I don't understand the drawing

Comment: @Tekton_infernus you're welcome! if my answer has been useful you can mark it as accepted

Comment: Even if the assumption of uniform distribution were justified, this answer says that if the centre of the coin lies anywhere in the box, it will fall in. Even at the corners, where almost 3/4 of the coin hangs outside the box.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus : if the center of the coins falls in any points inside the red square, the coin cannot overlap the black square. if the center of the coin falls outside the red square, on the contrary the coin overlap the black square

Comment: @JMoravitz : obviously I perfectly agree with you...I was just to give a very basic answer

Comment: There are two outcomes when playing the lottery, you either win or you lose.  You do not win half of the time however.

Comment: My comments were deleted for some reason by a moderator.  I stand by what I wrote earlier and will reiterate, I find this answer incorrect and the assumptions made to arrive at this answer unjustified and not based in reality, citing the real world examples of target practice not conforming to uniform distributions under normal circumstances.  This answer makes the sin of assuming uniform distribution which is rarely if ever the correct assumption to make which leads to the absurd claim in my remaining comment that you win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ which is clearly wrong.

Comment: If the moderator who chose to delete my comments and/or those who flagged my comments for deletion would like to justify the deletions, I would like to hear their opinion on why, but as it stands I can not in good conscience leave this answer as it is without strongly voicing my objections to it.

Comment: The probability given in this answer assumes that the center of the coin always lands uniformly over the interior of the box and only over the interior of the box. My guess would be that the distribution of where the center of the coin lands would tend to be a normal distribution, not uniformly within a sharp square.

Comment: @JMoravitz sorry m8 .I'm new to this kind of probability.But just listen alright? suppose I have a robotic hand that can move anywhere inside the box which will toss the coin .Excluding factors like resistance and other craps idk and assuming no factor will mess with the coin(maybe thats uniform distribution) this answer may be right.And I flagged you.Just because you are a prick good sir